# Staying for 8-12 months on Visit Visa

Tags: visas, malaysia, long-stay-visas, visa-runs

What is the best and easiest way to stay in Malaysia for 8-12 months without going back home.

I heard we can do via crossing borders. If we do in that way we need visa of Singapore or Thailand, if yes which category visa we need visit or transit.

Also, it will be on arrival visa or i need to get that visa from Malaysia ?

Comment: Where are you from (nationality)? What do you want to do in Malaysia? What you refer to is called "visa runs" and their use is discouraged. Also better suited for expats SE IMHO.

Comment: from Pakistan, Just want to stay with a love one who is on student visa :)